# Css not working after a while

Tags: html, css, web

I am a newbie and this is my first ever try on creating css,css worked fine until line 10...And i cant figure out whats my problem. Background and font colors are temporary :D Thanks a lot in advance!!

```css
body {
  background-image: url('bg.jpg');
  color: #000385;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.5
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline in links */
}
.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* everything will be centered */
  width: 70%;
  /* no floating elements */
}
.mainheader img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2% 0;
  /* leaves a bit of space on the top of the image */
}
.mainheader nav {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainheader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainheader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <img src="logo.png" <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="Homepage">
    <div class="content">
      <article class="maincontent">
        <header>
          <h2><a href="#" title="About Photography">About Photography</a>
         </header>
         <content>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
       </article>
      
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">

       <p>All rights reserved &copy </p>
```

Comment: Remember that every value should have a corresponding unit, for example: `line-height: 1.5em;` The only exception is zero value, which can be without of unit ;).

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide us more, such as your HTML code.

Comment: I really do not know whats wrong thats why i am asking you guys,by not working i mean that no matter what i styling i do there are no changes..

Comment: Can you provide us your HTML code? This is only CSS.

Comment: If you are running a windows machine hold ctrl + f5 to force a hard refresh of your browser. Otherwise just use the history option of your browser to delete the cache as that could be a reason why it wont update. Especially if it did before.

Comment: As stated in the answers below your mark up is messy but it seems being rendered correctly in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/soqowf5x/. Still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your markup a.k.a **(HTML)** your CSS is ok, and needs some improvement, so make sure you study CSS as well as HTML.

> Okay, but what is the mistake you might be asking.

HTML needs closing and opening tags, most tags come in pairs just like the body tag:

```
<body></body>
```

Other tags are self closing

```
<img src="" alt="" />
```

If you also notice the above tag has something called `src` & `alt` attribute, these are name/value pairs and these need the closing and opening double quotes `"`.

If you want to progress on HTML, and CSS here are some good resources

- http://css-tricks.com/
- http://htmldog.com/

And for you example here is a link to a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zmddh4r/1/)** with working code.

Comment: `img` tags don't need to be closed in HTML5 also

Comment: @JacekKowalewski no it shouldn't even though HTML5 does allow it, it doesn't mean you should abuse it in that way. You code wouldn't validate at W3C.

Comment: @JacekKowalewski Minimal HTML5 document is `<!DOCTYPE html><title>text</title>`.

Comment: Right, deleted my comment :).

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn no but they do need a final '>'

Answer (score 0):

The `<img src="logo.png"` is not closed.

You didn't close the `<nav>` element.

You didn't close the `<h2>` `<h2><a href="#" title="About Photography">About Photography</a>`

Replace the `<content>`

Also, you should close the `<footer>`.

Comment: With what should i replace the <content> ??

Comment: with <article> for example.